# Is there a Signal/Telegram/other bot to monitor wallet/address activity?

Tags: tools, bots

Pooltool.io monitors rewards and can notify via a Telegram bot on Pool activity, blocks and staking changes.

Is there a bot tool that can monitor wallet activity live, onchain?

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to checkout the Oura project: https://github.com/txpipe/oura

Essentially, it turns all the block and tx activity into a reactive stream you can plug into Kafka or other streaming sink.

Then its just a matter of wiring the output of a filter up to whatever messaging service you want.  Given that this is a "reactive" solution, you have greater control over back pressure and you aren't going to be beholden to rate limits imposed by blockfrost.  In my experience, reacting to streams of data, in this way, is a bit less cumbersome than having to poll a REST API.

Answer (score 1):

There is not that I know of.

But it would be trivial to build, using [blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io) with [signal-bot](https://github.com/TapuCosmo/signal-bot).